# MySQL Datatypes - Signed Unsigned

Tags: php, mysql, sqldatatypes

Let us consider TINYINT. [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp) says that it's signed range is from -128 to 127 and its unsigned range is from 0 to 255.

1) Why does it say that its range is from -128 to 127 and why not that its range is from -128 to 255.

2) Do these ranges mean that I can't take a value of -129 or 256 ? (Let's say I am filling a form where I have a textbox)

Comment: 1. Because `its range is from -128 to 255` is not true. 2. Yes, you __can not__ use `tinyint` for 256 or -129.

Answer (score 2):

`TINYINT` is represented via 8 bits (1 byte).  Basic knowledge of Information Theory says that *only 256 distinct values* (256 = 2^8) can be represented with 8 bits.

The 8 bits of "tinyint" are [*interpreted by MySQL*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html) in one of two ways:

- `TINYINT UNSIGNED`, where the 256 values are *interpreted* as `0..255`
- `TINYINT SIGNED` (alias `TINYINT`, since `SIGNED` is the default),
  where the *interpretation* has a range of `-128..127`

When the top bit is `0`, the 8 bits represent 0..127 identically between `SIGNED` and `UNSIGNED`. But when the top bit is `1`, the 8 bits either represent negative numbers or larger positive numbers.

If you wanted to, you could *interpret* the 256 values as meaning 'red', 'yellow', 'green', etc.  This is exactly what happens with a different datatype:

```
ENUM('red', 'yellow', 'green')
```

Another *interpretation* of 8-bit bytes gives you [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters.  See `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, `TEXT`, etc.

Since `TINYINT` must be either `SIGNED` or `UNSIGNED`, you *cannot* have a `TINYINT` column with both of these values: -111 and 222 (in different rows).  If you need that, then use `SMALLINT SIGNED`.  (This leads to a discussion of 16-bit representations of number.)

Answer (score 1):

Range of signed and unsigned are same it's all about optimization. unsigned is only for upper bound means it not allow negative number. So when you know you only need positive number always use ununsigned.

check it [here](https://rakesh.sankar-b.com/2010/08/25/mysql-unsigned-int-to-signed-int-performance-tips-index/)

Comment: "So when you know you only need positive number always use ununsigned." This part helped... Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

tinyint value is not from -128 to 255 that is why they don't say it.

While creating a table it is either signed or unsigned. If you don't specify then default is signed -128 to 127. If you specify unsigned while creating a table, its value is from 0 to 255.

```
CREATE TABLE `example_table` (
  `example_col` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL
);
```

The second answer is "Yes", you cannot use the value from -129 or 256 in tinyint. Check this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) to get an idea of upper and lower limit of each.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped. I gen. use PHPMyAdmin. So I will create unsigned from Attributes dropdown option.